# Hibernate native query that returns an object with nested properties for GraphQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, graphql, spring-graphql

**Is it possible for a native Hibernate/Spring database query to return an object structure that contains nested properties? Ultimately I want to return the data to a GraphQL query. I'm using [Spring for GraphQL](https://spring.io/projects/spring-graphql) and want the following request satisfied:**

```
query Query {
    someField {
        prop1
        prop2
        complexProp {
            prop3
            prop4
        }
    }
}
```

What *does work* is to return a flattened version of the graph as you see below. I'm okay with working with the flattened version, but I would prefer a graph with nested fields for complex objects. Here is what *does work*:

```
query Query {
    someField {
        prop1
        prop2
        prop3
        prop4
    }
}
```

I'm able to generate the above flattened graph by using `Transformers.aliasToBean` (aka, `ResultTransformer`), like so:

```
var query = """
        select p.prop1      as prop1,
               p.prop2      as prop2,
               c.some_prop1 as prop3,
               c.some_prop2 as prop4
        from parent p
                 inner join child c on c.parent_id = p.id
        """;

var results = (List<ParentWithChildFlattenedDto>) entityManager.createNativeQuery(query)
        .setMaxResults(100)
        .unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ParentWithChildFlattenedDto.class))
        .getResultList();
```

If I were using managed entities instead of a native query, I know the nested graphql structure could be built by doing one of two things:

1. The "new" operator in JPQL
2. Interface projections

thx